# One of my urls are not getting translated, giving me a 404 error

Tags: django, python-3.6

I'm currently having a issue with translation and url patterns on Django 1.11 using [this approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns).

Here is my **urls.py**.

```
from django.conf.urls import url  # noqa
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from core.views import HomeView, SolutionsView, SolutionView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(_(r'^solucoes$'), SolutionsView.as_view(), name='solutions'),
    url('{solutions}/{solution}$'.format(
        solutions=_(r'^solucoes'),
        solution='(?P<slug>[\w-]+)'
    ), SolutionView.as_view(), name='solution')
]
```

The url with name `solutions` work, but `solution` does not, giving me a 404 error, even when I translate and run the `compilemessages` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.format` on urlpatterns doesn't work. I've noticed that the right approach (used in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns)) is to wrap the whole url in the `_`.

Wrong:

```
url('{solutions}/{solution}$'.format(
            solutions=_(r'^solucoes'),
            solution='(?P<slug>[\w-]+)'
        ), SolutionView.as_view(), name='solution')
```

Correct:

```
url(_(r'^solucoes/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$'), SolutionView.as_view(), name='solution')
```